# What is alternative to oledb provider when using access (mdb) linked tables agains sql server in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, ms-access

As we know sql-server 2012 will be the last to support oledb. So what will be the alternative in future to address access linked tables?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an alternative, because linked tables from access to SQL server never used an oleDB connection.  The only exception is the rarely used access data projects, but for regular access databases that utilized linked tables to SQL server, then all of your forms an even record set code will continue to function as before.

About the only exception I can think of is someone has some types of code that uses anything other than the default connections built in to the Access development system.

In fact even if you look at the brand new latest edition of the Access 2010, it has baked in support for the cloud edition a SQL server (Azure).  And once again you'll find that using the standard built in table linking tools that a bit in access for 18 years will work fine in this scenario to Azure, and this of course means you are using ODBC.

So from an Access developer point of view for the vast majority of access developers they will do absolutely nothing and their linked table applications to SQL server will continue to function as they always have.

So at the end of the day it's important to keep in mind that linked tables for Aaccess applications never used an oleDB connection. The only exception to this was those who used what is called a Access Data Project. Access data projects were in fact native oleDB connecitons to sql server, and obviously such Data Products will not work with SQL server, but as I pointed out few people used Data Products with linked tables to SQL server a anyway, and as a result at the end of the day the vast majority of your applications won't have to have any code change whatsoever, and you'll continue to simply used the linked table manager that's been in access and available I think from nearly day one.